# CSS3 transform only working in Chrome, not in Firefox or IE

Tags: html, css, web

The transform:rotate property of my stylesheet only works on google chrome even when I put `-moz-transform:rotate` - Here is my code:

```
.hand1 {
position: absolute;
top: 480px;
left: 420;
-ms-transform:rotate(-45.5deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45.5deg); 
-o-transform:rotate(-45.5deg); 
-moz-transform:rotate(-45.5deg); 
-webkit-rotation-point:50% 0%;
 z-index:1;
}




.hand2 {
position: absolute;
top: 460;
left: 440;
-o-transform:rotate(-32.5deg); 
-moz-transform:rotate(-32.5deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(-32.5deg); 
-webkit-rotation-point:50% 0%;
z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add a transform: rotate(-45.5deg); for standards

Comment: @ziz194 Could you provide a jsfiddle for the issue you are seeing? Also I am not seeing a `transition` property in your above CSS, do you have them listed?

Comment: it is long code a just took a part of it , the idea is rotation for cards . it is only working on chrome with the code above

Comment: Have you added transition properties? Normally when I encounter an issue with transforms not working, it usually boils down to missing `transition` properties for the animation.

Comment: yes i've added the transition properties .

Comment: @ziz194 - I'm having the same issue, did you manage to find a fix for this? I've got all the correct -webkit, -moz and the standard included, and the `<li>`s are inline-block as others have said. Still animations only working in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Your element must be displayed as a block.

```
display: block;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: still have the same problem

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?
Try adding a width and a height.